# Moving MSDB database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, msdb

When I am trying to move msdb database from it's default location (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA) to another drive(E:). After moving the database I am getting error as shown below.(the error I am getting while expanding database node in SSMS and now I am not able to access any database.)

> Failed to retrieve data for this request.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ---
>
> Database 'msdb' cannot be opened due to inaccessible files or
>   insufficient memory or disk space.  See the SQL Server errorlog for
>   details. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 945)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.00.2531&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=945&LinkId=20476
>
> ---

The procedure I followed to shift msdb database is as follows:

1. For each file to be moved, run the following statement.

`ALTER DATABASE msdb
 MODIFY FILE ( NAME = MSDBData , FILENAME = 'E:\MSDBData.mdf' )`

ALTER DATABASE msdb
 MODIFY FILE ( NAME = MSDBLog , FILENAME = 'E:\MSDBLog.ldf' )

1. Stop the instance of SQL Server to perform maintenance.
2. Move the file or files to the new location.
3. Restart the instance of SQL Server or the server.
   Also i did confirm the path by running following query

`SELECT name, physical_name AS CurrentLocation, state_desc
     FROM sys.master_files
     WHERE database_id = DB_ID(N'msdb');`

And output was showing current location of both MSDBdata and MSDBLog as E:\

This error happened while I did it for testing server. I want to do it for a production server. So please help me on this error. How exactly to move msdb database?

Comment: Does the SQL Server service user have proper permissions on that drive? I remember I had permission problems in the past when moving db files on the root of the drive (IIRC on a Win Server 2008). Try to create a new folder and give your service user full permissions on the folder.

Comment: I do have full permission.I also checked the error in windows authentication mode, same error repeated.

Comment: Not your user. The SQL service has another login, by default, if you haven't configured otherwise. It should look like "LocalSystem", "Network user"..something like that. See in the list of services -> Log on as.

Comment: logonas has value 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE'

Comment: Does the `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE` account have NTFS permissions to read/write to the root of the E: drive where your msdb database files are located?

Comment: @mugawump How to check whether NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE has permission?

Comment: Right click the drive -> Properties -> Security -> Edit -> add the Network Service user -> give him full control. By default he hasn't. Or better, just create a specific folder and give him Full Control permissions there. And move the data files in that folder.

Comment: i added network service to E: drive add gave full permission and it worked. What exactly is network service? Does it cause any other problem to disk while considering security?I mean i have restriction for some users to that drive in our network

Comment: @winman if the answer worked for you, please mark it as such. Don't leave the question hanging, if it's not needed :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you indicate that your SQL Service is running as the `Network Service` account.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272(v=vs.85).aspx

> The NetworkService account is a predefined local account used by the
>   service control manager. This account is not recognized by the
>   security subsystem, so you cannot specify its name in a call to the
>   LookupAccountName function. It has minimum privileges on the local
>   computer and acts as the computer on the network.

This is the default account for installations under Vista and Windows Server 2008. During installation this account was granted `Full Control` file system permissions to the SQL Server data directory as seen in the **File System Permissions Granted to SQL Server Per-service SIDs or Local Windows Groups** section of the following article.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx#Reviewing_ACLs

Since you have relocated some of your database file the SQL Server service account needs permissions to the new locations. In the comments @Marian provided instructions for granting `Network Service` the required permissions.

> Right click the drive -> Properties -> Security -> Edit -> add the
>   Network Service user -> give him full control. By default he hasn't.
>   Or better, just create a specific folder and give him Full Control
>   permissions there. And move the data files in that folder.

The advice to create a new folder and move the files there is excellent as well.

Any additional services that are running as the `Network Service` account will aslo have permissions to this folder. Ideally the SQL Services should each have their own separate account.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2160720

> When choosing service accounts, consider the principle of least
>   privilege. The service account should have exactly the privileges that
>   it needs to do its job and no more privileges. You also need to
>   consider account isolation; the service accounts should not only be
>   different from one another, they should not be used by any other
>   service on the same server. Do not grant additional permissions to the
>   SQL Server service account or the service groups. Permissions will be
>   granted through group membership or granted directly to a service SID,
>   where a service SID is supported. For more details please refer to
>   Books Online Topic Setting Up Windows Service Accounts